# fluxbox keyboard switch german, greek (modern) and polytonic greek

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xkb, fluxbox

Where can i find a list of keyboard-layout codes to switch between german, greek (modern) and polytonic greek in fluxbox menu?

```
vim ~/.fluxbox/menu

[begin] (fluxbox)
[include] (/etc/X11/fluxbox/fluxbox-menu)
[submenu] (Keyboards)
[exec] (de) {setxkbmap de}
[exec] (greek) {setxkbmap greek}
[exec] (polytonic greek) {setxkbmap polytonic greek}
[end]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst` has all options and variants for xkbmap
polytonic is a variant so would use `setxkbmap gr -variant 'polytonic'`.
Fluxbox menu look correct.